# Azure V4 function - unable to get multi-response output binding to work for async function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-async

I am working on an azure v4 function running in dotnet-isolated mode using a multiple response (HttpResponseData and Cosmos DB Output binding)

The code worked when it was called synchronously, recently I started getting an error saying synchronous calls are not allowed.

The issue I have is when I change the return type to be *async task*, it returns the HttpResponseData to the client as expected but does not write out to the CosmosDB.

In the log I can see the following error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: IFeatureCollection has been disposed

Updated Error info. It is returning status 500 with the following (abbreviated) detail:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: IFeatureCollection has been disposed.

> Object Name 'Collection'

> at Microsoft.Azure.Function.Worker.RPC.RpcExtensions.ToRpcHttpSync (.NetWorker.Grpc\RpcExtensions.cs)

> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request)

My MultiReponse class is defined as:

```
public class MultiResponse {
    [CosmosDBOutput(databaseName:.....]  // Response 1 gets written out to cosmosdb
    public MyDBRecord item {get;set;}    // A class with three public string properties

    public HttpResponseData httpResponse {get;set;}  // Response2 goes back to the client
}
```

My Azure function had the following definition.

```
public MultiResponse Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
```

I basically changed the MultiResponse to async Task< MultiResponse >.  The routine that prepares the response is.

```
MultiResponse resp = new MultiResponse
{
    HttpResponse = req.CreateResponse(statusCode),
    Item = myDbRecord  // Basically a class with 3 public string properties.
};

 resp.HttpResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
 await resp.HttpResponse.WriteStringAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDbRecord));

 return resp;
```

I am wondering if I need to change the output binding or something to handle the change to being async.

Comment: At first glance, it seems like the routine that is preparing your `MultiResponse` is running on a different thread to the main function, causing the `HttpContext` to be disposed before you actually need it. Can you post a more complete version of the code so we can see exactly where everything is being called and handled?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the  code is in the main body of the function - it is the only code there at the moment.  I removed the async from the writeString to no avail.   I have updated the error info in my earlier post with more detail.

Comment: @AndyW Can you please share your full function code?

Comment: You have it - put the brackets {} around the multi-reponse section (after the run) - that's all I have.   Basically,  standard function template with an HttpResponseData and CosmosDBOutput binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update.

To get it working I needed to remove the async keyword and also any await methods.  I still needed to keep the Task as the return type.

Also, any awaitable calls in the method body needed to be changed to use the Task<Response> functionAsync() calling style.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you're attempting to access your `Request` or `Response` from outside its scope, which is causing it to get disposed.
You might want to try this, to see if it resolves the issue:

```
var response = req.CreateResponse(statusCode);
response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    await response.WriteStringAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDbRecord));

return new MultiResponse() 
{
    Item = myDbRecord,
    HttpResponse = response
}
```

This should make sure that you're not attempting to modify your `response` after it has been committed.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying.  While I get a valid document back in the client (the response portion is working), the CosmosDB remains empty (nothing is written) which means the output binding no longer works.  When I debug, the VS2022 is breaking into the grpFunctionsBindingsFeature module and I am seeing an exception in the function emulator window  'IFeatureCollection has been disposed'